# MacOS Catalina mouse/system hiccups when external monitor connected via Green Cell USB-C Hub

Tags: catalina, performance

I saw past posts about this issue but it's still hitting me on the current MBP 2019.
I'm using external iiama black hawk external display monitor connected via [Green-Cell USB hub](https://greencell.global/en/startseite/1954-docking-station-adapter-hub-usb-c-hdmi-green-cell-7-ports-for-macbook-pro-dell-xps-lenovo-x1-carbon-and-others.html)

Whenever I connect external display, the computer seems to stop every couple of seconds - the mouse freezes for 0.5s, terminal also - that's very irritating.
Somehow it seems, that I can get rid of this behaviour by changing the connection order of the external monitor but also not always.

I don't see any drivers/firmware to be downloaded, anyone having the same effect and has any workarounds?
Obviously plugging and unplugging in the right order until it works is quite irritating...

Comment: I’ve had similar issues with Mac mini when using a hub. Are you using Bluetooth mouse or wired?

Comment: The problem with asking the question like you did "anyone having the same effect" it attracts "me too" responses which don't actually answer the question.  I suggest rewording the question so that you can get something tangible  like a solution or a workaround.

Comment: @bjbk I'm using Bluetooth mouse, but I just checked, and the cursor stops if I move mouse OR use trackpad. I just now even turned BT off totally and the effect is still the same.

Comment: I have a similar issue on a 2019 iMac with a USB C to video connector going to a second monitor.  Strange thing is that the issue happens more when the second monitor is not displaying Mac content.

Comment: I switched from https://greencell.global/en/hub-usb-c/1954-docking-station-adapter-hub-usb-c-hdmi-green-cell-7-ports-for-macbook-pro-dell-xps-lenovo-x1-carbon-and-others.html to https://greencell.global/en/startseite/3034-green-cell-hub-gc-connect60-8in1-thunderbolt-3-usb-c-hdmi-3x-usb-30-sd-microsd-for-macbook-pro-1315-2016-2020.html and now all works perfectly fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a broken `Green-Cell USB hub`.
When I changed it to the newer model it works perfectly fine!